# With the new update I can't reload my world on the Xbox

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

When I got on it today it wouldn't let me reload my world.  Then I created a new one I saved and quit.  It wouldn't let me reload that one either.  Tutorial doesn't work either why?

Answer (score -1):

Try flushing the cache on the hard drive and download the update again:

http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/settings-and-initial-setup/clear-system-cache

If this doesn't work alone, delete all files associated with the game in the "Games and Apps" section of your hard drive manually.

Comment: I did that but it made me download it again

Comment: And you attempted to reload your save and it still doesn't work? The latest update always has to be used when online.